# Unityで機械学習をしたい

Tags: unity3d, 機械学習

Unityでモデルにボールを蹴らせて枠内に入れば報酬を与えてそれを重ねることでより良いシュートフォームを作るというのをやってみたくて試みています。
体全体は難しいのでまずは右足の腰から下の太もも、膝、すね、足首、足で作ってみようと思っているのですがここで質問です。モデルは全て作った後にスクリプトなのですが蹴るという動作を含んでしまうとシュートフォームが変わらないので学習できないので動ける範囲と報酬だけ(その他当たり判定など)を決めてあげて動かすとアニメーションとしての動きを書いていなくても学習を始めれば報酬を得るために勝手に動いて貰えるもんなのでしょうか？そうであれば範囲の決め方スクリプトの書き方を教えていただきたいです。やっている方が少なく困っております。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score -1):

まず他の機械学習の例を参考した方がいいです、機械学習の基本も学んだ方がいいと思います、「強化学習」を調べてみてください。